# Testing Whether a Binomial Distribution Fits Data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, chi-squared-test, binomial-distribution

I have a sample from a discrete distribution as such:

```
 Type:          0   1   2   3   4   5   
 Occurrences:  88  12  52  43  21   5
```

My task is to test whether or not a Binomial Distribution (n=5,p) fits this data.

I understand that I'm meant to use hypothesis testing, and that the chi-square test is a staple for this sort of task. I looked at [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/650775/testing-if-data-has-a-binomial-distribution) but I'm still not sure how to set up the test. How do I do this?

Comment: Please add the `self-study` tag and read its [tag wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info)

Answer (score 6):

Steps in carrying out a chi-square goodness of fit for a binomial:

1. Compute an efficient estimate of $p$. The usual estimator will do nicely.
2. Calculate the probability of getting Type $i$ for each $i$, given that Type is drawn from a $\text{binomial}(n\hat{p})$.
3. Hence calculate the expected number of observations at each Type.
4. Compute the chi-square goodness of fit statistic $\sum_i\frac{(O_i-E_i)^2}{E_i}$.
5. The d.f. for the test will be the number of categories minus 1 for the equality of $\sum_iO_i=\sum_iE_i$ and minus another 1 for the estimation of $p$. You could look up chi-square tables to find the critical value or use a package to find the p-value from the CDF of the chi-square.

Comment: If you are testing whether the observed values match the binomial distribution for a specific probability p, then are the d.f. for the test the number of categories minus 1?

Comment: If the p is prespecified rather than estimated, you don't lose that degree of freedom for the estimation, so yes.